# Visual Studio Code not running code in terminal

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-code, c

I'm trying to run my C code, but I keep getting this message in the terminal instead of the output I want.

I think it has something to do with installing MinGW incorrectly (or putting the wrong route into vscode) because MinGW is able to work if I run code through windows command prompt.

Sorry if I'm not making much sense since I'm relatively new to programming. Here is what the terminal tells me when I try to run code:

```
PS P:\comp sci\projects> cd "p:\comp sci\projects\" ; if ($?) { gcc CW714a.c -o CW714a } ; if ($?) { .\CW714a }
p:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: p:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:\temp\gcc\build-mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt/../../src/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
PS P:\comp sci\projects>
```

[image: CLI otput]

Comment: Hello, this is more suitable for StackOverflow. Also, I'd start by formatting your code properly, so that it's more readable.